# How to use “Java range slider“ in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, jcomponent

I have noticed that MATLAB support a few jcomponents founded in without any additional downloading, I know how to define a “Java range slider“ but i need to use to set its two values or get the two values and so on. Could any one please help me with some basic operations?

```
jRangeSlider = com.jidesoft.swing.RangeSlider(0,100,31,100);  % min,max,low,high
jRangeSlider = javacomponent(jRangeSlider, [0,0,200,80], gcf);
```

every thing I know is set and get the first knob value only

```
set(jRangeSlider,'Value',70);
```

Comment: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/sliders-in-matlab-gui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two different sliders and link them to each other by making the maximum value of the first one is the minimum if the second one and change it dynamically by the changing of the first one...